# How to paint() with QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: python, pyside2, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I am using PySide2 and I cant find any documentation on how to use the paint() function in a QStyledItemDelegate subclass. I am rather new to classes but is so far understandable but having trouble with PySide2.

I would like to replace my QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem with my own ListWidgetItem and display them correctly, like this:
[image]

So on the left of the ListWidgetItem an icon a bit to the right the name of the ListWidgetItem and underneath the description.

Here is the code:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PySide2.QtGui import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Test Window')
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);")

        mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        self.boxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(self.boxLayout)

        # Add Widgets
        self.textField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        self.textField.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)

        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.textField)
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.textField.setFocus()


    def onTextChanged(self, ):
        titles = ['Monkey', 'Giraffe', 'Dragon', 'Bull']
        descriptions = ['Almost a homo sapiens sapiens', 'I am a Giraffe!', 'Can fly and is hot on spices', 'Horny...']

        if self.textField.text() == '' or self.textField.text().isspace() or self.textField.text() == ' ':
            if self.listView.count() > 0:
                self.listView.clear()
        else:
            if self.listView.count() > 0:
                self.listView.clear()
            for x in range(len(titles)):
                if self.textField.text() in titles[x]:
                    item = ListWidgetItem(titles[x])
                    self.listView.addItem(item)
                    self.listView.setCurrentRow(0)
                    continue


class ListWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, title = '', description = '', icon = QtGui.QIcon()):
        super(ListWidgetItem, self).__init__()
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.icon = icon


class ListViewStyle(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent, itemModel):
        super(ListViewStyle, self).__init__(parent)
        self.itemModel = itemModel

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        if index:
            return QtCore.QSize(40, 40)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(ListViewStyle, self).paint(painter, option, index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None: 
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Info: In onTextChanged() the ListWidgetItem will be added to the QListWidget but not drawn correctly, basically empty.

Does QListWidgetItem have any notable difference to QListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate only paints and is not interested in what element provides the information since that class uses the QModelIndex and the same model to obtain the information, so in [my previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806687/6622587) I used a QStandardItemModel that uses QStandardItem and in your current case a QListWidget with QListWidgetItem is indifferent. My delegate expects only that the information of the title, description and icon are related to TitleRole, DescriptionRole and IconRole, respectively.

On the other hand it is not good to delete the items but it is better to hide or make them visible when necessary.

Considering the above, the solution with QListWidget is as follows:

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

TitleRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
DescriptionRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001
IconRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1002


class ListWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, title="", description="", icon=QtGui.QIcon()):
        super(ListWidgetItem, self).__init__()
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.icon = icon

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.data(TitleRole)

    @title.setter
    def title(self, title):
        self.setData(TitleRole, title)

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self.data(DescriptionRole)

    @description.setter
    def description(self, description):
        self.setData(DescriptionRole, description)

    @property
    def icon(self):
        return self.data(IconRole)

    @icon.setter
    def icon(self, icon):
        self.setData(IconRole, icon)


class StyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QtCore.QSize(50, 50)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(StyledItemDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
        title = index.data(TitleRole)
        description = index.data(DescriptionRole)
        icon = index.data(IconRole)

        mode = QtGui.QIcon.Normal
        if not (option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled):
            mode = QtGui.QIcon.Disabled
        elif option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            mode = QtGui.QIcon.Selected

        state = (
            QtGui.QIcon.On
            if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open
            else QtGui.QIcon.Off
        )
        iconRect = QtCore.QRect(option.rect)
        iconRect.setSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        icon.paint(
            painter, iconRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter, mode, state
        )

        titleFont = QtGui.QFont(option.font)
        titleFont.setPixelSize(20)
        fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(titleFont)
        titleRect = QtCore.QRect(option.rect)
        titleRect.setLeft(iconRect.right())
        titleRect.setHeight(fm.height())

        color = (
            option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.BrightText)
            if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected
            else option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.WindowText)
        )
        painter.save()
        painter.setFont(titleFont)
        pen = painter.pen()
        pen.setColor(color)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawText(titleRect, title)
        painter.restore()

        descriptionFont = QtGui.QFont(option.font)
        descriptionFont.setPixelSize(15)
        fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(descriptionFont)
        descriptionRect = QtCore.QRect(option.rect)
        descriptionRect.setTopLeft(titleRect.bottomLeft())
        descriptionRect.setHeight(fm.height())
        painter.save()
        painter.setFont(descriptionFont)
        pen = painter.pen()
        pen.setColor(color)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawText(
            descriptionRect,
            fm.elidedText(description, QtCore.Qt.ElideRight, descriptionRect.width()),
        )
        painter.restore()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Test Window")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);")

        mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        self.boxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(self.boxLayout)

        # Add Widgets
        self.textField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        self.textField.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)

        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.textField)
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.fill_model()

        self.textField.setFocus()

        self.listView.setItemDelegate(StyledItemDelegate(self))

    def fill_model(self):
        titles = ["Monkey", "Giraffe", "Dragon", "Bull"]
        descriptions = [
            "Almost a homo sapiens sapiens",
            "I am a Giraffe!",
            "Can fly and is hot on spices",
            "Horny...",
        ]

        for title, description in zip(titles, descriptions):
            it = ListWidgetItem(title=title, description=description)
            self.listView.addItem(it)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        text = text.strip()
        if text:
            for i in range(self.listView.count()):
                it = self.listView.item(i)
                if it is not None:
                    it.setHidden(text.lower() not in it.title.lower())
        else:
            for i in range(self.listView.count()):
                it = self.listView.item(i)
                if it is not None:
                    it.setHidden(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: "On the other hand it is not good to delete the items but it is better to hide or make them visible when necessary." Why?

What are the TitleRole, DescriptionRole and IconRole for?

Comment: @Lala_Ghost 1) If you remove and add items you are creating dynamic memory that perhaps in python is very common and necessary for that reason it is not given the necessary interest but analyzing the background that has a cost of time (memory request) in addition to making unnecessary repainting in the GUI; it is something similar to `a = [1, 2, 3]` `a = a + [4,5]` and `a.extend([4,5])`.

Comment: @Lala_Ghost 2) The delegate does not know or should know the type of model used or the view to which it will be applied, this means that it can be applied for one modelX and viewX and not have to change anything in the delegate for another modelY and viewY. As you have noticed, the same delegate has been applied to both views without changing anything in the delegate. Roles are labels that are given to the information that you want to store in a model so that it can be accessed by the other GUI elements that need that information.

Comment: @Lala_Ghost  I recommend you read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html for more details.

Comment: Okay, I am gonna read the link you gave me. But I still have trouble do grasp the solution you gave me...

Comment: @Lala_Ghost Well, unfortunately SO is not a tutoring service to explain everything you previously had to learn about Qt views.